# React pass props parameters into State variable

Tags: reactjs

I've seen many questions and answers about this issue, but I still can't figure out what is the right way to achieve this with **react 18**

What is the right way to send parameter via props into a child component to be used in a state parameter ?

my current code looks like this - but it seems wrong - the data is not there when I need it:

```
const ChildComp = (props) => {
   const [selectedTenant, setSelectedTenant] = useState(null);
   const [scheduleID, setScheduleID] = useState(0);

   useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.scheduleID && props.scheduleID > 0)
        {
            setScheduleID(props.scheduleID);      
            setSelectedTenant(props.selectedSchedule.TenantID);
        } else
        {        
             // some other code in case scheduleID is not passed
        }
    },[])

}
```

Is there a better way to initialize the state parameters ?
I use them later in the JSX code and looks like they keep the null/0 values and only after being rendered the useEffect code runs.
The user will be able to change the tenant id (using react-select) hence the state is needed...

Answer (score 1):

pass relevant props to useEffect dependency array

```
},[props.scheduleID, props.selectedSchedule.TenantID])
```

Comment: that is the only change ? I've read now that this is an anti-partern. but not sure what is the right pattern,

Comment: Yes, this will retrigger the useEffect when the schedule or tenant ID change

Comment: this will not work, as props.selectedSchedule can be undefined (if scheduleId is 0) the code will break.

Comment: then remove the tenant id and keep selectedschedule. add an if condition inside useeffect to see tenantid is not undefined

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in your case is using this method:
Avoid using states and call the props conditionally
Ex:

```
{props.scheduleID || {otherValue} }

{props.scheduleID > 0 ? {props.scheduleID} : {OtherValue }
```

Or you can put the whole logic in a method and use it:

```
const showValue = (prop, alternative) => prop > 0? prop : alternative

{showValue(props.scheduleID, 'otherValue')}
```